# How to count pixels using AXI Stream signals?

Tags: vhdl

I was trying to count pixels based on the signals from the AXI stream signals like `tuser` and `tlast`. I wrote this:

```
  p_pixelcount : process (s_clk)
    variable v_hcount : integer := 1; 
    variable v_linecount: integer:= 1;
  begin
  if (rising_edge(s_clk)) then
    if (s_maxis_s_tvalid_out = '1')and (s_maxis_s_tready_in = '1') then 
        if ( rising_edge(s_maxis_s_tuser_out) ) then
           v_hcount    := 0;
           v_linecount := 0;
        else 
           v_hcount := v_hcount + 1;

        end if; 

        if (s_maxis_s_tlast_out = '1') then
           v_hcount := 0;
           v_linecount := v_linecount + 1;
        end if;

    end if;
  end if;
  end process p_pixelcount;
```

I received the following simulation outputs [image]

My questions:

1. When `tuser` is high, shouldn't the `v_hcount` be `0`?
2. Is it allowed to use two `rising_edge(signal)` conditions on different signals in the same process?
3. I want to count till `tlast` and then in the next cycle the count is set zero. Is it possible to do this without using a signal?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First off: don't make `v_hcount` and `v_linecount` variables. They are clocked, so need to be registered: use signals for that. (for synthesizable code)

No, you cannot use `rising_edge` twice in a process like this. If you want to detect a 0->1 transition, you need to do that in the (correct) clock domain. E.g.

```
s_maxis_s_tuser_out_delay <= s_maxis_s_tuser_out when rising_edge(s_clk);
s_maxis_s_tuser_out_rising <= 
    '1' when s_maxis_s_tuser_out = '1' and s_maxis_s_tuser_out_rising = '0'
    else '0';
```

but in this case you should probably just use

```
if (s_maxis_s_tuser_out = '1') then
    v_hcount    <= 1;
    v_linecount <= 0;
else 
    v_hcount <= v_hcount + 1;
    if (s_maxis_s_tlast_out = '1') then
       v_hcount <= 0;
       v_linecount <= v_linecount + 1;
    end if;
end if;
```

Why do you initialize the `v_hcount` and `v_linecount` at 1, but reset them to 0?

Comment: Thank you for the rising_edge info, that cleared my query.

Comment: I tried using the second method yesterday, but `v_hcount`would be 0 after one cycle i.e. the clock cycle for tuser = '1' does not get counted and number of pixels in the first line was 1 less.

Comment: I initialized them to 1 just to see when does it become 0.

Comment: @user3094049 I don't understand what you want to achieve. So when `tuser = '1'` you want `v_hcount` to become 1? Then just set it to 1 instead of 0... see my edit